# extracting country, city and venue from google search

Tags: java, google-search-api

I need to extract from **venue** **country**, **city** from google search result. For example I search for "EEE Symposium on Computational intelligence for Image Processing". I'm using googles custom search api.

I get a snippet like this,

```
"snippet": "The Computer Security Foundations Symposium is an annual conference for 
researchers in ... It was created in 1988 as a workshop of the IEEE Computer 
Society Technical Committee on Security and ... CSF-26 was held at Tulane 
University, New Orleans, LA, June 26-28, 2013. ... CSFW-19 program and 5-
minute talks.",
```

How do I extract 'Tulane University, New Orleans' from the response....mind you there are multiple results but lets assume I take only the 1st one which contains this..

Answer (score 1):

This is difficult, given that you're handling natural language. There are a few possibilities. It really depends on the input.

1. You could try finding these using templates/regex. If you know that venues are introduced by "held at" or "organized at" etc, you can use that information to extract the venues/locations.
2. You could use a POS/NE Tagger to tag the words. Using the Standford CoreNLP Pipeline yields (shortened, using only relevant sentence and information):

   CSF-26 NN O
   was VBD O
   held VBN O
   at IN O
   Tulane NNP ORGANIZATION
   University NNP ORGANIZATION
   New NNP LOCATION
   Orleans NNP LOCATION
   LA NNP LOCATION
   June NNP DATE
   26-28 CD DATE
   2013 CD DATE

   The word is followed by the POS tag, followed by the NE entity tag. O stands for "Other", the rest should be self explanatory. You could then look for LOCATION and surrounding LOCATION or ORGANIZATION.
3. You could use a database of geographical names to find COUNTRY/CITY, then look at the x surrounding words. If you can also provide a list of commonly used "venue" names, you can include that to further ameliorate the results. This step can be integrated into any other method as well.

---

This list is not exhaustive. It depends greatly on the variance of the input.